# Looping through a list to add characters to a list of Strings in Java

Tags: java, foreach, linked-list

I'm trying to create a method that returns a linked list of Strings.  There is a tree, and each node in the tree stores a character.  The method is supposed to find all possible paths through the tree.  Each path creates a string, which is added to the list.

There seems to be a problem within the second for loop that I can't figure out.  The method only returns characters that were added in the first if statement.

each node contains the variables childList, which is a linked list of children nodes, and nodevalue, which is the character that the node is storing.

```
public LinkedList<String> findStrings() {
    LinkedList<String> paths = new LinkedList<String>();
    //add character to list if there are no children
    if (childList.isEmpty()){
        paths.add("" + nodevalue);
        return paths;
    }
    //use recursion to add paths from all children to the list
    for (TreeNode t : childList){
        paths.addAll(t.findStrings());
        //add nodevalue to the beginning of all strings in the list
        for (String s : paths){
            s = nodevalue + s;
        }
    }
    for (String s : paths) System.out.println(s); //for debugging
    return paths;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you change `s` in the inner loop, you're just re-assigning the variable `s`, not the value stored in your linked list. Instead, you should loop through all the elements in your list updating them one by one. I think something like this should work:

```
//use recursion to add paths from all children to the list
for (TreeNode t : childList){
    paths.addAll(t.findStrings());
    //add nodevalue to the beginning of all strings in the list
    int length = paths.size();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        paths.offer(nodevalue + paths.poll());
    }
}
```

`poll` takes the first item from the front of the list, and `offer` puts the result on the back. You take the first item off, change it, then put it on the back—repeat `paths.size()` times and you end up with the updated items in the original order.

Comment: Alternatively, using a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to update values while iterating would work nicely too.

Answer (score 1):

String is an immutable type the assignment

```
s = nodevalue + s;
```

is not regognized

A better solution should be

```
for (TreeNode t : childList){
    final List<String> pathes = t.findStrings();
    for (final String path : pathes) {
      // add all pathes to paths list adding nodevalue to the beginning
      paths.add(nodevalue + path); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The enhanced for loop is not going to help here.

You are going to have to go with the traditional one as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++){
    paths.set(i, paths.get(i) + paths.get(i));
}
```

Here: [`public E set(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

Comment: Random-access `set` and `get` aren't the best choice with a `LinkedList`. Also, `s` was the loop variable in his version...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `s`, missed that. Also your point about the random access is right. I just decided to use it because the documentation doesn't mention that it's optional and `LinkedList` itself is an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
for (String s : paths){
            s = nodevalue + s;
}
```

You're not actually changing the value of s. In fact, you can't the way you're doing it now. A for-each loop can not change the elements that it is iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

as Michael said you can't replace the values of an entry in a for each loop. And since Strings are immutable you can't change the existing string.

You'll need to perform a normal Loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<paths.size(); i++) {
    paths.set(i, nodevalue +paths.get(i));
}
```

Note that you don't change the value of the existing String but replace it with a new String at the same location.

Comment: If you're going to recommend using `get` and `set` you should also recommend switching to `ArrayList` instead of `LinkedList`. (`LinkedList` has terrible random-access performance—probably because it's a linked list.)

Comment: @DaoWen: You are right. I don't understand why he is using `LinkedList` here instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @BheshGurung - Since he specifically says he wants to create a linked list, I was assuming he was doing this for a reason. `ArrayList` isn't actually the _panacea for all your collection woes_ that so many people seem to think it is. ArrayLists are good for random access, but they suck for adding/removing items anywhere but the end. LinkedLists suck for random access, but you can add items wherever you want cheaply. Which one is the right choice really depends on your application.